# Why is the print() function not printing what I ask it to in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, python-3.x

Just for fun, I'm building a very simple text-based game in Python 3.2. My development machine is running Windows 7, and I'm using the [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter) IDE to develop this game.

I'm running into a slight problem with the `print()` function not printing a string out correctly. When you begin the game, the program displays a small menu with 3 choices: `Login`, `Register`, and `Exit`. When I go to register, the program creates an object from a custom class I made called `Character`. The character takes in a `name` variable, and then prints out a small message using the name variable. Here's the code that I have to do that:

```
user_choice = int(input("Please select a command: "))
if user_choice == 1:
    print("Sorry, this function isn't currently implemented.",
    "Please check back later.\n")
elif user_choice == 2:
    hero_name = input("Please choose a name for yourself, adventurer: ")
    hero = Character(hero_name)
    print("I see, so your name is", hero.name + "... Very well. We shall begin your journey immediately!\n")
```

The code should work properly, and when I run the program in PyScripter, I get a nice output:

> I see, so your name is (the name I chose)... Very well. We shall begin your journey immediately!

But, when I run the program from the cmd-prompt, I get:

> ... Very well. We shall begin your journey immediately!

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a fault on Windows?

Comment: I get the exact thing in both cases, namely "Name 'Character' not defined". You probably need to enter a complete example. There's nothing wrong with the code you pasted here.

Comment: The `print` function automatically adds a newline at the end (unless you specify the parameter `end=''`), so you don't need these '\n' here (of course, if you don't want an empty line after the output). About the question... I agree to Lennart's comment.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there's a typo in your `print()` statement:

```
# You have this:
print("I see, so your name is", hero.name + "... Very well. We shall begin your journey immediately!\n")

# Did you mean this?
print("I see, so your name is" + hero.name + "... Very well. We shall begin your journey immediately!\n")
```

Comment: Oh, hello there, Mr. Inconstancy! I fixed the typo, but the error still remains. Thank you for pointing that out me!

Comment: Damn, I hate the people that upvoted this. I'm seeing that the number of upvotes depents mostly on how easy the question is, not on how good the answer is.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Unfortunately it didn't help with 1n73rn37_j3d1's error, but it isn't wrong as `+` is needed for string concatentation, and the OP acknowledged that.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Python 3.2 with Eric5 IDE:

```
heroname = "Joe Cool"
print("I see, so your name is", heroname + "... Very well. We shall begin your journey immediately!\n")
```